# Array become string when passing in session in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an array as key in a hash stored in session in Rails.
The code looks like:

```
array = ["a", "b"]
session[:likes] ||= {}
session[:likes][array] ||= []
session[:likes][array] = ["c", "d"]
```

However, the output looks like:

```
> session[:likes]
> {"[\"a\", \"b\"]"=>["c", "d"]}
```

Why would my array become a string?
Is there any way to prevent my array becoming string?

**Update and Alternative**:

I end up using `join(",")` to convert the array `[a,b]` to a string `"a,b"` before saving into session. Then use `split(",")` to convert the string to array `[a,b]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why would my array become a string?

The Rails session store use a `json` serialization. `json` can't have an array as key:

```
=> a
=> {:likes=>{["a"]=>["b", "b"]}}
=> a.to_json
=> "{\"likes\":{\"[\\\"a\\\"]\":[\"b\",\"b\"]}}"
=> JSON.parse a.to_json
=> {"likes"=>{"[\"a\"]"=>["b", "b"]}}
```

That's why your array become a string.

> Is there any way to prevent my array becoming string?

While you use the `json` serialization, no way.

Answer (score 1):

Rails session data is always converted to JSON.

```
session[:likes] = ['one', 'two', 'three', ['four', 'five']]
```

You can however add a function that returns this value in array form in, for example, application_controller.rb. Then it's available to you in all your controllers.

```
def session_likes
  JSON.parse(session[:likes])
end
```

This way when you call `session_likes` you'll get the array you expect.